# Remove nth element from redis's list in thread safe way

Tags: php, multithreading, redis

In a cron job, I wish to remove nth element from redis's list, in thread safe way during iteration.

Is it something possible? May I know how I can do so?

I'm looking for thread safe way. There will be another writer process, which will perform write operation into the same list from time-to-time.

```
while (true) {
    // Get all elements from "mylist" list.
    $list = $redis->lrange("mylist", 0, -1);

    // Iterate through "mylist" list.
    for ($n = 0; $n < count($list); ++$n) {
        if ($list[$n] == "dummy") {
            // I wish to remove nth element (with "dummy" value) from "mylist" 
            // in thread safe fashion. But how?
        }
    }
}
```

Thread safe is important such that the following situation won't happen

1. Cron job find out "dummy" element is the 5th element, and prepare to remove it.
2. Writer process is inserting additional element into the head of list, which pushes "dummy" element into 6th position.
3. Cron job removed 5th element from the list, which is no longer a "dummy" element anymore!

In Java, I usually solve this reader/writer problem by using [Copy On Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) (through [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)). But, how about in PHP & redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LREM](http://redis.io/commands/lrem) to do this:

```
LREM mylist 0 "dummy"
        ^   ^    ^
        |   |    |- `value` to delete   
        |   |------ remove all elements equal to `value`.
        |---------- list key name
```

You may use `count` (0 in sample above) to moving from head to tail (or tail to head).

Comment: And for completeness, since Redis is (mostly) single threaded, LREM is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this can be by using thread safe php (by installing thread safe binary for php on windows or installing pthreads extension for php). As far as redis is concerned , it is single threaded so one list will be updated once at a time. However loops can be managed (which actually modify Redis lists ) by executing them in thread safe fashion.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pthreads.php